# incorporate loops and arrays into my code

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

for a project that i am doing in a programming class I am making a Trivia game. Right now i have three multiple choice questions and after each question i have four buttons with possible answers that the user can click. If they get the answer right, a check will show up beside the question. That is all my program does. For my project, i need to also incorporate at least one loop and one array. Any ideas of the kinds of things that i can add? Here's my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Geography Trivia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="firstproject.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Geography Trivia </h1>
    <h3> Questions: </h3>
        <p> where is the atacama desert located? </p>
            <button onclick="displayPromptOne()">Africa</button>
            <button onclick="displayPromptOne()">Canada</button>
            <button onclick="displayPromptOne()">Russia</button>
            <button onclick="showCheckOne()" >South America</button>
            <img id="checkOne" src="check.jpg" style="height: 45px; width: 45; opacity:0;">
        <p> Which Lake in Canada has the most volume when compared to all other lakes in the world </p>
            <button onclick="showCheckTwo()"> Raindeer Lake </button>
            <button onclick="displayPromptOne()"> Anderson Lake </button>
            <button onclick="displayPromptOne()"> Tagish Lake </button>
            <button onclick="displayPromptOne()"> Teslin Lake </button>
            <img id="checkTwo" src="check.jpg" style="height: 45px; width: 45; opacity:0;">
        <p> Which U.S. state is nicknamed "the sunshine state"?</p>
            <button onclick="displayPromptOne()"> California </button>
            <button onclick="displayPromptOne()"> Arizona </button>
            <button onclick="showCheckThree()"> Florida</button>
            <button onclick="displayPromptOne()">Pheonix </button>
            <img id="checkThree" src="check.jpg" style="height: 45px; width: 45; opacity:0;">



<script>
function showCheckOne() {
    document.getElementById('checkOne').style.opacity= '1'
}
function showCheckTwo() {
    document.getElementById('checkTwo').style.opacity= '1'
}
function showCheckThree() {
    document.getElementById('checkThree').style.opacity= '1'
}

function displayPromptOne() {
    alert("Sorry, wrong answer! Try Again");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could have an array of questions, from which you could be randomly picking a fixed subset to ask the user. This will require you to both use arrays and loops; and will seem to bring up random/new questions on every reload.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myGradesThisYear = ['D-', 'F', 'D', 'D+', 'F'];

for (var index = 0; index < myGradesThisYear.length; index++) {
  alert("If I don't learn to do my own homework I'll never pass these classes.");
}
```